# XMLParser enclosure attributes for AEXML library

Tags: ios, swift, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am using a XMLParser Library. I have a xmlDoc and I don't know how can handle some tag values. For example:

```
<item>
<title>.....</title>
<description>....</description>
</item>
```

If I have like above xml works fine. But when I want to parse like below xml I cant do it.

```
<item>
 <enclosure type="image/jpeg" url="https://www....."/>
 <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://www"/>
</item>
```

Library url: 
[AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML)

I can retrieve  like this:

```
if let items = xmlDoc.root["item"].all{
for item in items{
print(item["title"].string)
}
}
```

But I dont know how can get enclosure.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: what isn't working?

Comment: Actually I dont know how can retrieve enclosure url. @dprogramz

Comment: The main page of the library you linked to shows an example of getting the attributes of an element.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated my question, I cant get as attribute. Do you show me an example?

Comment: As I said, there is an example at https://github.com/tadija/AEXML

Comment: @rmaddy print(xmlDoc.root["cats"]["cat"].attributes["breed"]!) I cant apply this for me. Thus, I said can you give me example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply apply the example to your XML:

```
for item in items{
    if let enclosure = item["enclosure"] {
        if let url = enclosure.attributes["url"] {
        }
    }
}
```